# .htaccess redirect 301 setup help question please

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am having a problem with setting up `.htaccess` redirect 301.

Say I have an example website: `example.ca`

I used to have the following url available: `example.ca/old`

but now I want to redirect it to new url which is `example.ca/new`

I deleted the url of `example.ca/old` so if someone tries to access that url, they will get 404 error.

How can I redirect "already removed url" which is example.ca/old to example.ca/new?

I have tried the following `.htaccess` setup, but it did not work:

```
Redirect 301 /old example.ca/new
```

Can someone please point out what I have done wrong?

Comment: How did you get on with my answer? If this answered your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /old example.ca/new
> ```

This will result in an Internal Server Error (500 response) due to the missing slash prefix (or scheme + hostname) on the target URL.

However, if you are redirecting to the same domain (as in your example) then you don't need to explicitly include the hostname in the target URL. Therefore, the following should suffice:

```
Redirect 301 /old /new
```

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Note that if you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file then order matters (redirects usually need to go near the top) and if you have existing mod_rewrite directives then you might choose to use mod_rewrite instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^old$ /new [R=301,L]
```

Note that the first argument to the `RewriteRule` directive (ie. `^old$`) is a *regular expression* and the URL-path matched by this does not start with a slash.

Comment: @DanielChung You're welcome. If this answered your question, then please mark it as "accepted" (tick/checkmark on the left below the voting arrows) to remove it from the unanswered question queue and to help other readers. Once you have 15+ rep then you can also upvote answers you find useful. Thanks, much appreciated. :)